# Send a big string to a server in Android

Tags: android, json, http

I want to send 15 images to a server and I use json objects to convert these images in a String, but when i want to send it, is some devices there are Out of memory exception because there is a big string.

My images has 320x400 more and less and i do this:

First I create a jsonarray with one object to each image:

```
for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
        Mat aux = images.get(i);

        int cols = aux.cols();
        int rows = aux.rows();
        int elemSize = (int) aux.elemSize();

        byte[] data = new byte[cols * rows * elemSize];

        aux.get(0, 0, data);
        String dataString = new String(Base64.encode(data, Base64.DEFAULT));

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            obj.put("ROWS", aux.rows());
            obj.put("COLS", aux.cols());
            obj.put("TYPE", aux.type());
            obj.put("DATA", dataString);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        arrayjson.put(obj);

    }
```

And the i create a json object with contains this array and another params:

```
final JSONObject jsontoSend = new JSONObject();

        try {

            jsontoSend.put("USERNAME", user.username);
            jsontoSend.put("DATE", getCurrentDateandTime());
            jsontoSend.put("IMAGES", arrayjson);
            jsontoSend.put("TOTALIMAGES", images.size());


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Finally, i try to send this object:

```
StringEntity send = null;
        try {
            send = new StringEntity(jsontoSend.toString());
        httpPost.setEntity(send);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -2;
        }
```

How can i do to send this big string??

Thanks

SOLUTION:

I solved this adding in my Manifest file  `android:largeHeap="true"`with this, android increase my app memory and runs fine

Comment: How large are your images? Maybe try using inSample to reduce the size. Or failing that, use an AsyncTask and send one at a time. That way you can better manage your memory. Not even FTP programs upload 15 files at once. You're asking a mobile device to do something that even desktop devices wont usually do.

Comment: I updated my question to show how manages my images

Comment: I meant "how large" as in actual file size (i.e. bytes used to store the image in the first place), not dimensions. In this instance image dimensions are quite useless. If you'd rather, total up the combined Kb of all 15 images and let us know that.

Comment: Total size of data to send is arround 12 Mb

Comment: I think that i solved this problem. I add in my Manifest file      android:largeHeap="true"